# Script for uninstalling device and reconnecting wifi

Tags: windows-10, powershell, shell, vba, device-manager

Without any luck in fixing a [related problem with a certain hardware component](https://superuser.com/questions/1436720/alternatives-to-uninstalling-device-from-the-device-manager) and no successful solutions from the official ASUS support, I would be interest in automatizing the uninstall of the device through some shell script.

Essentially, since the device is known, some identifying code could probably be hardcoded. In essence, the script should do the following:

1. Find device in the device manager.
2. Perform the equivalent of "right click -> Uninstall -> Yes"
3. Turn off Wifi
4. Turn on Wifi
5. (nice-to-have): check if the device exists (i.e., is automatically reinstalled by Windows), repeat 1.) if yes.

It would be perfect to have something like that crontab'ed in Windows 10. But having no scripting experience in Windows I'm not sure whether a) it's even possible; b) how hard it is to implement due to various securities. Are there similar examples? Where could I begin? Is this the correct SE to ask this?

Note: While this may actually be an XY problem, so far the best that ASUS support can offer is to Warranty/Service the device, which is currently the least attractive option.

Environment: Windows 10 Education 64bit, ASUS GL504GM machine.

---

**Closed:**
Added an answer with a working script, if anyone else would run into the same issues.

As for my specific case, the ASUS support claims that the issue is hardware based and suggests a repair (which I never got round to, since I can't afford losing the machine for months for a tiny issue like that).

Comment: Add to your question: Windows-10 32 or 64-bit? What device?

Comment: @somebadhat Windows 10 Education 64-bit on ASUS GL504GM Laptop.

Comment: What hardware component/device isn't being recognized?

Comment: @JW0914 [here are more details on the specific problem and device](https://superuser.com/questions/1436720/alternatives-to-uninstalling-device-from-the-device-manager). "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller" is only useful for ethernet connection which I never use, so I'm fine with uninstalling the device, as long as it helps with the WiFI connection.

Comment: I've found that using PowerShell, ``(Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver -filter "DeviceName='Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller'")`` is able to find the device installed, however I'm still not sure how to properly interact with it from here. Methods like ``.uninstall()`` or ``.delete()`` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Why not just install the [correct driver](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/advanced-search/72?Itemid=276) for it?

Comment: @JW0914 it did not help the problem. Nor did the latest drivers for the WiFI card, or any other related service drivers (multi antenna, wireless radio and similar, provided by the oem).

Comment: @Nutle Please elaborate... what exactly is the core problem?  Also, network drivers should be downloaded directly from the manufacturer of the network component, not the PC manufacturer.  PC manufacturer drivers that must be utilized are the CPU, GPU, touchpad, etc. where the OEM has made significant customizations to those specific drivers that using a generic driver from the component manufacturer would result in functionality loss.  Audio drivers, network drivers, card readers, etc. should be downloaded from their respective manufacturers, and the link I provided is RealTek's.

Comment: @JW0914 the exact problem with the GBE device is the following. This is tested with these latest drivers: Realtek GBE: 10.37.1028.2019; Intel 9560 (WIFI): 21.50.1.1. If everything is running by the default as it should, when using the WiFi connection, the speeds are throttled to 10 Mbps (~2MB/s) speeds (along with some minor stability issues that are harder to describe). Now, If I do the following steps, ALL these problems are solved. 1) Uninstall the Realtek GBE device (disabling doesn't help) 2) Turn off WiFi on Windows 3) Turn on Wifi again.

Comment: @JW0914 What I have tried and didn't work: 1) updating the drivers 2) playing with the settings of Realtek And Intel cards (1GBPS full duplex, various energy and speed settings) 3) downgrading the drivers. Clearly the GBE is meant for ethernet/LAN, not wifi, but it seems to somehow interfere with the wifi connection, though I do not have the expertise to dig any deeper. Is the problem clear enough? I will add, that I found about uninstalling the Realtek device purely by accident, by trying to uninstall a ton of various devices from the device manager, by a pure hunch of some interference.

Comment: @Nutle It would be more efficient to try and get at the underlying issue via troubleshooting on a forum like [Spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/), where the majority of the members are people who work in IT.  Microsoft also has dedicated [vendor] employees that participate in troubleshooting issues.

Comment: @JW0914 Thank you, will take a look there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found code that seems to work (on my machine). For anyone else with similar problems, use the code with caution, there are two variables that should be modified: The `FriendlyName` and the `-Name` of the NetAdapter.

```
# Find all Realtek devices:
$Devs = Get-PnpDevice -class net | ? FriendlyName -like "*Realtek*"

if ($Devs.length -gt 0) {
     ForEach ($Dev in $Devs) {
         Write-Host "Removing $($Dev.FriendlyName)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
         $RemoveKey = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\$($Dev.InstanceId)"
         Get-Item $RemoveKey | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property | %{ Remove-ItemProperty -Path $RemoveKey -Name $_ -Verbose }
     }
     Write-Host "Done.  Restarting wifi." -ForegroundColor Green

     # Restarting the wifi:
     Get-NetAdapter -Name Wi-Fi | Restart-NetAdapter
     Write-Host "Done. " -ForegroundColor Green
} else{
    Write-Host "All looks good." -ForegroundColor Green
}
```